# Do Roller Shades have Universal mounting brackets so I can switch out?

Tags: windows, brackets, blinds

Do Most Roller Shades have universal mounting brackets? I want to maybe switch roller shades every couple years between different company manfacucturers? This way I don't have install drill holes for different mounting brackets each year.

[image]

Comment: Are you rotating between several sets you own, or constantly buying new ones?

Comment: Quick empirical test - find your nearest big-box DIY store, see if any two manufacturers use the same fixings. [Chances are low]. If not, change between different designs from the same manufacturer. tbh, I think this is a non-problem. Re-fixing new brackets is a 5-minute job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount a short section of t-slot rail on the wall, then mount the brackets to the appropriate t-nuts that slip into the rail.

T-slot rail:

[image: t-slot rail]
<sup>Images courtesy of Amazon.com. Click to embiggen</sup>

"Official" t-slot nuts:

[image: t-slot nut kit]

Note that the key item is the bolt head that slips into the t-slot. Any old bolt of the right length would work, and a simple nut, possibly with a lock washer, will hold it in place. An acorn nut would be more decorative. You probably don't want those ginormous winged handles on your wall beside your shades.

You might need to mount the rail on a wooden block to mount it to the wall, and you might also need to mount the brackets to another block of wood. The aluminum rail can easily be drilled to make additional mounting holes where you need them, since these are designed to be used in long stretches, not short bits of only a couple of inches.

Comment: Good idea, but let me just fetch my elephant gun to kill this house-fly;)) Bang some match-sticks or cocktail sticks in the old holes & off you go again ;)) tbh, I've never in my life drilled a pilot for something as simple as a 90° angle bracket for a blind. Wood screws for wood, or self-drillers for anything else.

Comment: You say that, @Tetsujin, as if changing out the shades every year or two isn't a bit over the top... ;)

Comment: I think the OP is asking whether the size of the roller endpin is universal, so he does not have to replace the mounting bracket due to the different sizes (endpin vs hole on the bracket) when mating, not the width of the shades or the position of the brackets.

Comment: LOL I change my venetians when the strings get too yuk that a day in bleach & high-power degreasant in the bath no longer fixes them.

Comment: With this method, @r13, each blind could have its own mounts so they can be swapped whether they match up or not.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about it. It is ok then if it turns out nice to view.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, yes they are universal.  Because when you order them, you do not specify a size.

[image]

Comment: If you Google Image 'roller blind brackets' you will find dozens of different designs. Incidentally, searching that from the UK finds nothing at all that looks like those.

Comment: The thing they all have in common is a round hole in one end and a rectangle slot in the other.